# Simple chat bot with a single context matching api.ai?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to do some thing like this with api.ai. I am doing it as a telegram bot.

1st  question: Tell me a joke?

Bot:           Tells a joke ( picks it from text response that I specified )

2nd input from user: Some more.

Bot:           It should tell another joke from the same list of responses.

One thing I could do is include MORE as a user input is joke intent and  it would pick a response.

But I can not do this, because then even without asking 1st question if I give "more" as input it would pick a response from the list. Basically that wouldn't pick response based on context.

Any help onn the structure  I should be using on api.ai to  achieve something like this.

Comment: Matt gave the good answer below... If you wish, I wrote a post that show this specific use case (jokes for kids :) - https://medium.com/google-developers/build-your-first-smart-bot-for-google-home-18949f74822c

Answer (score 1):

So the first intent where the user asks "tell me a joke?" sets an outgoing context- 'jokes'.

Follow-up intents for telling more jokes have 'jokes' for the incoming context, and, if you want to chain repeatable requests, set the outgoing context as 'jokes' as well.

If the user input like "tell me more" outside the 'jokes' context is still triggering the followup intent, either train your bot to recognize the difference, or create an explicit "tell me more" example in a fallback intent outside the jokes context.

Comment: It works but then I need to have two intents for same set of text response. And if try to make the input and output context same for a single  intent, then I won't be able to enter that intent . Because it needs a context  as as input.

Comment: You just need one context for 'I'm already telling a joke'  First first intent outputs context Second intent inputs and outputs context